# Sending Mail with Angular and Firebase-Functions using Nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, angular7, nodemailer, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to pass data from angular to nodemailer form in firebase functions.

**This is code from firebase functions:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
admin.initializeApp();

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: '*******@gmail.com',
    pass: '******'
  }
});

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    // getting dest email by query string
    const dest = req.query.dest;
    const mailOptions = {
      from: '******@gmail.com', 
      to: dest,
      subject: "email", 
      html: `<h1>Hi there</h1>
          ` 
    };

    // returning result
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
      if (erro) {
        return res.send(erro.toString());
      }
      return res.send('Sended');
    });
  });
});
```

I want to replace dummy data: subject,html,to with data from angular typescript file.
How should i do it?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by “with data from angular typescript file”? Those data are in your application front end and you want to send them to the Cloud Function? If yes, how do you call the HTTP Cloud Function from your front-end (which library are you using for that? How do you pas the values in the request?)

Comment: Using Angular Http, managed to send data to cloud fuction, with request query params.                                                                                                                     async Get(sub, body) {
    const url = '****************/sendMail?';
    await this.http
      .get(
        `${url}dest=mail@gmail.com&naslov=${sub}&body=${body}`,
        { responseType: 'text' }
      )
      .subscribe();
  } Now i have problem, dont know how to send html file like body. I think max length is 120 characters for url.

Comment: If you do `const dest = req.query.dest; console.log(dest);` in the Cloud Function, do you see the correct value in the Cloud Functions log?

Comment: Note that you may use a POST request and put your form data in the body of the request, see https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: Yes, service works, i need now way to send html now.

Comment: Big tnx for help. @RenaudTarnec